# Multi Projector Setup

Tags: projector, presentation

Has anybody had experience with Multi Projector setups? I've been looking around and run across several options:

- [Watchout](http://www.dataton.com/watchout)
- [Wings](http://europe.avstumpfl.com/en/products/wingsav/vioso/preproduction)
- [Millumin](http://www.millumin.com/)
- [Pandoras Box](http://www.coolux.de/products/pandoras-box-player/)
- [Christie Projectors](http://www.christiedigital.co.uk/emea/pages/default.aspx)

The only type of presenting I've done is with a single [Panasonic PT-D6000US](http://www.panasonic.com/business/projectors/PT-D6000US.asp), we want to branchout and do a really wide screen show. It will not be for a live performance (it seems like that is a big feature with most of those applications).
There isn't a need for 3D mapping, the projectors will be mounted above the screen, so we'll need to correct for distortion. We'll have a curved screen, and will need some sort of triggering system, whether it is a motion sensor, sound or light sensor or just a button that can be pushed. So the question is, what is the most cost effective simple multi-projector setup.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Could you elaborate on te triggering system? What does it trigger? Just the next slide or transition?

Comment: @Bart Arondson as far as the trigger, what we want is a way to start the presentation when someone enters the room. It might mean that the presentation starts when a door is opened, or someone passes a sensor.

Comment: Ah I see. Isn't it easier to just have someone press the button when someone enters the room without fiddling with sensors? Of course it would be nice if it would work, but I would consider it more as a bonus.

Comment: @Bart Arondson It's absolutely a bonus! I'd just wanted to through it out, because it would be very nice...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, it might be as simple as using the drivers that come with your system.  I know that certain NVidia cards can make multiple video outputs appear as one single screen to Windows.  In a case like that, it would simply be a matter or properly aligning the projectors (if they can handle the key-stoning themselves)  A lens might be able to handle correcting for the curve.

Comment: The screen is going to be curved, so we need a way do digitally manipulate the lens distortion.

Comment: @circleb I am suggesting you may get better results with an amorphic lens.  It depends if you have a regular curve or not, but may yield better results than digital alterations. (Or at least cheaper)